# ebx register doesn't work in NASM but ecx work

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

```
section .data:
msg: db "Hello !"
msglen: equ $-msg

section .text:
      global _start:

_start:
      mov ebx,msg
      mov ecx,msglen
      mov eax,4
      int 80h
      mov eax,1
      int 80h
```

The code above doesn't work.
But code below is working good.

```
section .data:
    msg: db "Hello !"
    msglen: equ $-msg

    section .text:
          global _start:

    _start:
          mov ecx,msg
          mov edx,msglen
          mov eax,4
          int 80h
          mov eax,1
          int 80h
```

All of i did was change ebx to ecx and ecx to edx.
What is happen here ?

Comment: What errors do you get (if any) with the non-working code? How do you build? How do you run (if you can build)? Just what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You can't just randomly use registers. The system calls expect particular arguments in specific registers. See a [system call table](http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/syscalls.html). For sys_write `ebx` has to contain the file descriptor, `ecx` the buffer and `edx` the length. PS: I doubt you used `masm` that's more likely `nasm`.

Comment: nasm -f elf mycode.asm --> ld -m elf_i386 -s -o mycode mycode.o       i haven't getting error,builting stage seems ok,but output is nothing when i use ebx register

Comment: _" i haven't getting error,builting stage seems ok"_ The assembler and linker has no knowledge about the semantics of a system call. That's an operating system thing. You need to follow the calling convention specified by the OS.

Comment: @Jester Oh,thank you.i didn't know these informations.İs there any book that you're recomment for noobs like me ?

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all.  `section .text:` uses a custom section name that includes a colon, not the usual `.text`.  That usually breaks from a non-executable segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 2nd code works because `write(0, "string", len)` happens to work.  FD 0 is stdin, but in a terminal programs are normally run with all 3 standard FDs referring to the same file description that's opened read/write on the TTY.

So you can write to stdin unless you redirect it to a file.

The kernel zeroes all the regs before entering user-space at your `_start` entry-point, so EBX = 0 if you don't set it.  [`write(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) takes the file descriptor as its first arg.

**Use `strace ./a.out` to see your system calls.**

---

Your first code doesn't work because `write("string", len, 0)` passes a pointer as the file-descriptor number so `sys_write` will return `-EBADF` (or `-EFAULT` if it checks if `len` is a valid pointer first).  The only valid fds will be 0, 1, or 2 unless you use a redirect like `./a.out 12345>&1` to open fd `12345` as a duplicate of `1`.  Again, use `strace`.

**And read the docs about system-call calling conventions.  [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6) has links.**

See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for links to more docs/manuals and guides.